# Trying to pull the items from a list in Sharepoint but returning empty (Python)

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-api, python-o365

I do have a sharepoint website which is a list full of items.

When reaching that list using Python O365 module, I can see the properties of the list and it shows all information as it should be. Including the number of items which is around 1000.

But when doing the get_items(), it's returning empty :(

```
from pprint import pprint
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.lists.list import ListItem



client_credentials = ClientCredential(client_id,client_secret)
ctx = ClientContext(site_url2).with_credentials(client_credentials)

list_object = ctx.web.lists.get_by_id("HIDDEN") 
items = list_object
ctx.load(items)
ctx.execute_query()
pprint(items.properties) #THIS RETURNS ALL THE PROPERTIES OF THE PAGE
pprint(items.get_items()) #THIS RETURNS EMPTY
```

Any guesses? Thanks.

Comment: don't you need to store the results of `ctx.execute_query()` somewhere?